# Keypress event not working

Tags: jquery, keypress

I am using this code but keypress event not working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#txt_tempusername').keypress(function() {

            var href = $('#providerurl').val();
            href = href.toString().replace("{username}", $('#txt_tempusername').val());
            $('#btn_idgo').attr('href', href);

        });
    });

</script>
```

and this is my HTML

```
<div class="Input_Div">
 <input type="text" id="txt_tempusername" />
 <a class='example1demo' id="btn_idgo">Go&lt;/a>
 <input type="hidden" id="providerurl" />
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share the html code? Try alerting on keypress and make sure you have an input with the id `txt_tempusername`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working sample here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/6zfw8/2/

Guess the events worked fine but your 'href' treatment didn't work because the hidden fields value was not defined.

Fixed your code the way I think you wanted it to work:

**your html:**

```
<div class="Input_Div">
    <input type="text" id="txt_tempusername" />
    <a class='example1demo' id="btn_idgo">Go!</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="providerurl" value="http://provider-url-{username}.html" />
</div>
```

**your js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txt_tempusername').keyup(function() {
        var href = $('#providerurl').val().replace("{username}", $(this).val());
        $('#btn_idgo').attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

Comment: btw changed to keyup event, more reliable in this use case

Answer (score 1):

Put an

```
`alert("foo");`
```

in the function and see if you get a message box. If you don't get one, the element with the ID `txt_tempusername` does not exist.